# What is ambient occlusion in baked GI settings?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently struggling with lighting settings in Unity 5.4, and because I'm learning how to use them I'm trying to understand how every one of them works. I have problem with figuring out what ambient occlusion actually does. The discription in the docs also doesn't explain this clearly for me. Can somebody explain to me what this does - what's the effect, and what's the process of making this? Also it would be nice if you could explain what settings that appear after i pick ambient occlusion do(max distance, direct, indirect), in case that isn't obvious after explaining how AO works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An ambient light source represents an omni-directional, fixed-intensity and fixed-color light source that affects all objects in the scene equally. Upon rendering, all objects in the scene are brightened with the specified intensity and color.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading#Ambient_lighting)

So basically, this is the first "layer" of lighting that is applied to all objects in the scene.  Without any ambient light, everything would be pitch black.  On top of this, you can add directional lights, spotlights, and other light sources that will have occlusion on by default.

[Ambient occlusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion) basically changes how much lightning is applied to each face of the objects based on how exposed they are.  Without this checked, each point on each object will be lighted equally.  When it is checked, shading occurs.  For example, divots on the face of a model will appear dark as the light is being blocked by the more exposed areas.

Occlusion settings can also be calculated using what's known as an [Occulusion Map](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterOcclusionMap.html). You can create these in whatever third-party modeling software you are using to calculate how exposed each point is to ambient light.  These maps are basically just grayscale images where pure white means the point should receive full ambient light, and pure black should receive absolutely no ambient light.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question: AO is only calculated based on ambient source and geometry?